# What is the =!= operator in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've come across this operator in a Spark application written in Scala and would like to understand it. Example...

```
val filtered = df
    .filter(lower('entry) =!= "blah blah")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's just a method name like any other method name. It has no special meaning whatsoever.

It is also not a well-known method name in Scala. It seems to come from some library; you need to look at the documentation of whatever library you are using to figure out what it does.

In this case, it appears to be [`org.apache.spark.sql.Column.=!=`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@=!=(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

> ## `def =!=(other: Any): Column`
>
> Inequality test.
>
> ```
> // Scala:
> df.select( df("colA") =!= df("colB") )
> df.select( !(df("colA") === df("colB")) )
>
> // Java:
> import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
> df.filter( col("colA").notEqual(col("colB")) );
> ```

Answer (score 6):

That is [this method in org.apache.spark.sql.Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@=!=(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) which serves as an inequality test.

Answer (score 4):

you must use the =!= operator so that you don’t just compare the unevaluated column
expression to a string but instead to the evaluated one

source:spark-the definitive guide

Comment: what do you mean by unevaluated columns can you explain little bit ?